# Determine with Arduino if 220V AC power is on or off

Tags: arduino, power, current, ac

What would be ways to determine with example with Arduino, is current 220V AC socket on or off state? Any other than using relay (noisy) or current sensing sensor (too big)?

Comment: Current sensors aren't too big: The [ACS712 isolated current sensor IC](http://www.allegromicro.com/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs/ACS712.aspx) is `6 x 4.9 x 1.75 mm`, that sounds reasonably small. However, a current sensor will only tell you when current is flowing, not when the socket is on but without any current being drawn. Which of these statuses do you need to detect?

Comment: If the arduino were connected to the socket and there was a small battery on board that exclusively powered a flashing LED, it would be simple, nay trivial, to have the arduino preventing the LED flashing and when the power fails, the arduino goes high impedance and the LED flashes.

Comment: Are you aiming for contact or non-contact? Are you interested if power is getting to the socket or if the switch is on and power is getting out? Do you want detect voltage presence or current flow?

Comment: Small optoisolator, surely? Or even a socket with integrated neon indicator + photosensor, which avoids opening up the socket at all.

Comment: Is it not possible to just detect the EMF using something like this? http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-EMF-Detector/

It may need Calibration by checking the difference between the on and off state/what the background levels are, but I don't see why it can't work.

Comment: If the Ardunio is on fire, the mains is live.

Comment: Related question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17008/how-can-i-detect-a-power-outage-with-a-microcontroller

Answer (score 3):

Use any optocoupler in parallel with socket (of course, current-limiting resistor and reverse-polarity protection is necessary), and RC-filter on secondary side.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a serial usb charger.

Or you could use a hall effect current sensor like ACS712 (small).

If it is to know if a light is on, maybe a photoresistor on your arduino.

Comment: Can you please provide the circuit?

Comment: Search for "acs712 arduino" and you'll get a lot of circuits ;)