# Building a small 4-bit adder on a breadboard

Tags: integrated-circuit, breadboard, adder

I am very new to using IC and basically a breadboard in general, but I am doing a project on how computers add and thought it would be nice to have a practical demonstration.

My main question is, for the parts that I am going to list out, would a 5 volt input be ok? What size of resistor should I use to get a 9 volt battery down to 5 volts? And what size resistors would I need to use for the LEDs?

Parts:

- C&K BD01,
- Lumex SSF-LXH400SRD,
- ST M74HC08B1R,
- TI SN74LS32N,
- TI SN74HC86NE4,

I am new to all this.

Comment: Hi Jake, welcome to the site. Your user name and information appears at the bottom of every post so you don't need to include a signature.

Comment: @JYelton  ok, thanks, but I still deem it appropriate to leave a thanks, seeing as people are helping out and it is always kind to say thanks

Comment: There's a [substantial writeup on the topic at Meta SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/134987). I know what you mean, but it just adds "noise" to the questions. I think it's appropriate to show thanks by upvoting and accepting answers, and occasionally in comments it is certainly acceptable to occasionally say something like "This solution helped me the most, thanks."

Comment: Except you can't up vote until you have 15 points. Which I do not have on this part of stackexchange.

Comment: You'll be there before you know it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though a 5V power supply is suitable for the parts you have listed. The easiest way to generate this 5V from a 9V battery is using a 5V voltage regulator such as a 7805. A resistor won't be able to produce a reliable 5V source from 9V, because the current drawn by the circuit will not be constant. The 7805 needs a couple of capacitors close to it for stability (see, for example, figure 6 of [this datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7805.pdf%E2%80%8E)).

I note that you have a mixture of TTL (74LS...) and CMOS (74HC...) parts. Mixing logic families like this is often not guaranteed to work correctly, due to differing output and input voltages thresholds between the logic families. A very quick look at the datasheets for your parts suggests that high output voltage of the TTL part is possibly as low as 2.7V, whereas the CMOS parts may require at least 3.15V on the input to register a high value. Though this can be fixed with level translator chips or pull-up resistors, I would advise just getting some 74HC32 (or 74AHC32) parts to replace your 74LS32 ones.

See [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14852/how-do-i-calculate-the-resistor-value-for-a-simple-led-circuit) for a description of how to calculate the appropriate resistor for LEDs. However, I suspect that your LED current will be limited by the maximum output current of your chips. You can get this value from the datasheets for the logic chips. Note that there is usually a per-pin current limit, as well as a total limit for current provided or sunk by all outputs.

Though in this circuit you might get away without them, it is always advisable to put a 100nF decoupling capacitor across the power supply pins of each logic IC.