# Deciding On A Resistor For an LED

Tags: led, batteries, resistance

Let me preface: This is my first post on this exchange, so I will try to provide as much context as possible. If some details are lacking, or I've left this question overcooked, I apologize.

So, I am building a prop for an upcoming convention on the east coast, and part of it involves lighting. I've tried to reduce and streamline the amount of soldering and the like I will have to do, as I am on a budget of time and attempts, so this might seem a bit unconventional: I am making some light-up vacuum tubes with LEDs, and I was going to use the same method outlined here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Glowing-Steampunk-Flash-Drive/

The end result will be the same, however there will be four in total, and they will be powered by a bus-powered USB hub connected to a 16,500mAh battery, which is intended for charging smartphones, tablets, and other devices of the sort.

I wanted to use this warm white surface-mount LED right here: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/lumileds/MXA8-PW35-0000/1416-1094-6-ND/4031757

I believe I can mostly understand the relevance of each field on its little data sheet, but I need to be pretty much certain on a proper resistance.

So the question is, what resistor should I use for it? The Battery has two outputs, both 5 Volts, but one has a 1 Amp output, and the other is 2 Amps. The test current for the LED is 100 mA, and the maximum is 200 mA, with a forward voltage of 3.05 Volts. If I were to use a 22 ohm resistor, would that be proper for achieving ~roughly~ test voltage? Also, would the test voltage be particularly bright? If not, would it be smarter to order two sets of resistors, one for the maximum and one for the test? It has been a long time since I've done even basic electronics.

I just want to make sure I'm understanding this information correctly, and if I'm not, I would greatly appreciate a knowledge smackdown by someone who does. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One more update in my answer, just fyi.

Comment: related threads: [Correct formula for LED current-limiting resistor?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/17179/7036) and  [How do I calculate the resistor value for a simple LED circuit?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/14852/7036)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

200 mA will kill it in short order. That's the Absolute MAX.

100 mA and 65 mA are the nominal recommended max currents.

Formula for resistor is:

> (V Source - V LED Forward Voltage) / Target Forward Current
>   (V<sub>s</sub> - V<sub>F</sub>) / I<sub>f</sub>

( 5V - 3V ) / 0.1A = 20Ω

22Ω gives slightly less than 100 mA (2V / 22Ω = ~0.09A) will really **not** be noticeably dimmer, and will help ensure the stated life of the led is met. A target of 65mA might be better. 2V / 0.065A = ~30Ω. As @Asmyldof points out, enclosing the led in a tube, on thin wires, isn't the typical application the manufacturer expects (on a pcb board with adequate landing pads/copper sizing, and certain free air/distance).

Since you have 2 volts across the resistor at 90mA, that's 2 * 0.09 = 0.18 Watts. You will need a 1/4th Watt resistor. So smd resistors are right out unless you go with two 44 ohm 1206 (1/8th Watt) resistors in parallel. So stick to 1/4th or 1/2 Watt through hole resistors.

**Keep in mind, the original instructable used a 0805 20mA led. You want a 3535 led, thats normally 5 times bigger light area and 5x more current. It will be particularly bright and blinding in comparison. You will want to play around with one to find out a good brightness. Use a few resistors to test. Between 30Ω and 200Ω before finalizing which one.** And the more current used, the faster your usb power pack will drain. At 50mA you will have twice the battery life of 100mA, generally speaking.

Comment: "Will ensure the life of the LED is met" --> Only if it is mounted properly, which I have doubts about with an SMT device in the question "what resistance?" 300mW isn't a lot, but for a device dangling off two wires in an enclosed space, quickly too much.

Comment: @Asmyldof addressed.

Comment: LEDs light adequately at only a few milliamps.  If you just want to make a vacuum tube glow, rather than blind everybody who looks at it, a quite small current may be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If designing for simplicity, I'd probably use a current regulator, such as the [NSI45060JDT4G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NSI45060JD-D.PDF), which will act like a variable resistor with exactly the right value, regardless of input voltage.

Since you're running off battery, if you can accept more complexity then a switching regulator such as the [RT9284A/B](http://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9284A=RT9284B/DS9284AB-07.pdf) may be a better choice as they waste less energy as heat, but the downside is that you need a few extra components.

Comment: The first one has a Drop out of 1.8. With  a 5V supply and a typically 3.2 Vf led, that's cutting it close.

Comment: Good point, but LDO regulators for 100mA seem to be rare.